# Screen reader cannot read text which dynamically add to button

Tags: javascript, html, button

When when I click "click me" button, I dynamically change button(class="b_button") text which is an inline div(class="b_button_label"),  the text I set as `'Search for "${inputText}"'` (which with quotes) or `'Search for ${inputText}'` (which without quotes).

The button(class="b_button") which has the aria-label, and the aria-label I dynamically  set as `"Search for " + inputText`.

I find that if I add quotes, the screen-reader can  read out “search for butterfly button”(which I set to aria-label), “search for butterfly” (which is the content of div inside button) sequentially ,when I keeping pressing down key on button(class="b_button") ,like this code:

`let searchDescription = 'Search for "${inputText}"';//This text set to div`

But when I delete quotes, the Narrator read out “button” (doesn’t read out aria-label), “search for butterfly” (which is the content of div inside button) sequentially, when I keeping pressing down key on button(class="b_button") ,like this code:

`` let searchDescription= `Search for ${inputText}`;//This text set to div ``

How should I understand this?  Is it a charset encoding issue or other issues?

Is it accidentally that I add quotes to solve my problem? Or the essential issue I cannot find out?

Thanks for your help.

By the way, I want to screen-reader readout “search for butterfly button”, “search for butterfly” sequentially when I keeping pressing down key on this button.

My code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>
        Create custom shape button
    </title>
</head>
<body>  
    <p>
        <input name="name" class="b_input" id="b_input" value="butterfly"></input>
        <button class="b_create_text" onclick="Func()" width="100px">click me</button>
    </p>
    <button class="b_button">
        <div class="b_button_label">@("show me more information")</div>
    </button>
    <script>
        function Func() {
            let dir="ltr";
            let inputB = document.getElementById("b_input");
            let inputText = inputB.value;
            let searchDescription = 'Search for "${inputText}"';

            var sideBarLabelNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("b_button_label");
            if (sideBarLabelNodes.length == 1) {
                sideBarLabelNodes[0].textContent = searchDescription;
            }

            let el = document.getElementsByClassName('b_button');
            if(el.length == 1) {
                if(!!searchDescription) {
                    el[0].setAttribute("aria-label", "Search for " + inputText);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view code by inspect in browser, When I click "click me" button.

```
<button class="b_button" aria-label="Search for butterfly">
        <div class="b_button_label">Search for butterfly</div>
    </button>
```

Is it that the screen-reader cannot readout aria-label when it's value is equal to button's content which dynamically set?

Comment: Maybe attribute value is malformed like this `aria-label="Search for "butterfly""` . did you try with single quotes ``let searchDescription = `Search for '${inputText}'`; ``?

Comment: Hi @SrikanthKolli,  thank you so much. I have tried using single quotes according to your suggestion. It can be read out as I add quotes. I don't know why it works when I add quotes to div text. Why the dynamic text in div which inside button can effect aria-label on button? Is it related to charset or template string? Could you please give me some suggestions about this?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @SrikanthKolli, If I change one of the text which dynamically set to button's aria-label or it's sub-element content. make them difference. then the screen-reader can readout aria-label. Is there a rule or setting when screen-reader ignore aria-label on html element when it's value same as it's content?

Answer (score 0):

Using single / double quotes will be string.
backtick will be eval() / Template literals

sample code :

```
    function test() {
        let t = 'text1';
        let n = 1;
        console.log( "#1", t );
        console.log( "#2", "${t}" );
        console.log( "#3", '${t}' );
        console.log( "#4", `${t}` );
        console.log( "#5", eval( {t} ) );
        console.log( "#6", eval( "{t}" ) );
        console.log( "#7", eval( "{n+1}" ) );
        console.log( "#8", eval( "console.log(98)" ) );
        console.log( "#9", `${console.log(99)}` );
    }
    test();

    /*
        #1 text1
        #2 ${t}
        #3 ${t}
        #4 text1
        #5 
            Object { t: "text1" }
        #6 text1
        #7 2
        99 --> result by console.log(98)
        #8 undefined 
        99 --> result by console.log(99)
        #9 undefined
    */
```